# Help with Theorem 2.9.7 from Federer's Geometric Measure Theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, outer-measure, borel-measures

Suppose $\phi$ and $\psi$ are Borel regular measures (outer measures) on a metric space $X$ such that $\phi(A),\psi(A)<\infty$ for every bounded subset $A\subseteq X$. One defines a Borel regular measure $$\psi_{\phi}(A)=\inf \{ \psi(B) \, ; \, B \, \text{is a Borel set and} \, \phi(A-B)=0 \}$$ whenever $A\subseteq X$. The first step in the proof of Theorem 2.9.7 is to show that if $A\subseteq X$ is $\phi$-measurable then it is also $\psi_{\phi}$-measurable. It's clear to me that $A$ is contained in a Borel set $B$ such that $\phi(B-A)=0$, but why does this imply $\psi_{\phi}(B-A)=0$ ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $\phi(B-A)=0$ the you have: $ψ_{\phi}(B-A)=\inf\{ψ(C)|\phi((B-A)-C)=0\}$ where $C$ is borel. But the empty set is a borel set, and taking $C=\emptyset$ you have $\phi((B-A)-C)=0$ and $ψ(C)=0$ hence the infimum has to be less than or equal to $0$ and since it can't be negative you get $ψ_{\phi}(B-A)=0$

Comment: @Fotis Thanks. I was overthinking trying to use thm 2.9.2. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\phi(B−A)=0$ then from the definition of $\psi_{\phi}$, you have:
$$\psi_{\phi}(B−A)=\inf\{ψ(C)\big|ϕ((B−A)−C)=0\}$$
where $C$ is Borel.
But the empty set is a Borel set, and so if you take $C=\emptyset$ you have: $$\phi((B−A)−C)=\phi(B-A)=0$$
by assumption, and:
$$\psi(C)=\psi(\emptyset)=0$$
Hence the infimum has to be less than or equal to $0$ and since it can't be negative you get: $\psi_{\phi}(B−A)=0$

Comment: I'm studying the proof of Theorem 2.9.7 of Federer. Can anyone explain me where in that proof it is proved that A is $\psi_\phi$-measurable, please?

Comment: @Grace53 since $\psi_{\phi}(B-A)=0$, it follows that $B-A$ is $\psi_{\phi}$-measurable. We also have $A=B-(B-A)$. Thus $A$ is $\psi_{\phi}$-measurable.

Comment: Right! Thank you very much. You use the completeness of the measure $\psi_\phi$ restricted to the $\sigma$-algebra of all $\psi_\phi$-measurable subsets of $X$.